# Ext3 filesystem: Why does the blocks change after I edit an existing file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, computer-forensics

I am unclear why this happens. Reproduce:

```sh
# create file
$ touch mydocument.txt
$ echo "Hallo welt." > mydocument.txt
$ ls -li
24529 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tsurugi tsurugi    33 Jan 20 11:12 mydocument.txt

# So, I anaylse the inode with ID 24529 using the sleuth kit:
$ istat /dev/sdb 24529
...
Direct Blocks:
100352
```

So the contents of the file should be in Block number 100352  (blocksize is 4096Byte, ext3 filesystem on a 32G usb stick)

Checking that with dd: (and some math...)

```sh
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb status=none bs=32 count=1 skip=12845056 | hexdump -Cv
00000000  48 61 6c 6c 6f 20 77 65  6c 74 0a 00 00 00 00 00  |Hallo welt......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
```

So far, so good, Content there. Now I edit the file, and after that, the Direct Block is different (checking with istat again, same inode), containing the new content, AND the old Block ist still filled with "Hello world."

Anyone can explain why that is? Shouldnt the block containing the data be altered?

Comment: You said the direct block is different, so why would you expect the old block to change as it is no longer referenced?

Comment: Yeah I think I got how it works... :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because its a usb stick so less reliable for rewriting to the same location so a change will mean a 'new' file is created and the old file is left but no longer referenced, no reason to overwrite unless it has to if there is somewhere else to put the file less 'overwrite' wear on one specific sector if multiple changes are made